# How HiveMQ Clustering Works on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hivemq

In case of AWS,  S3-Buckets are used for Auto Discovery. Also, as per the document, “A message only gets forwarded to other cluster nodes if a cluster node is interested in it”. However, I am a bit confused about the message forwarding between nodes within cluster for a topic

1. What information is stored on S3?
2. How the forwarding node comes to know about the interested node for the topic. It seems some mapping on topic-vs-nodes are maintained. How this mapping is maintained?
3. As AWS does not support UDP Multicast. So, which underlying transport protocol is used in case of Auto Discovery and MQTT message forwarding?

Indeed it would a great help if somebody can answer this question.
Based on these inputs I would be able to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

This question was also asked on the HiveMQ mailing list and the blog post where this questions has some references to.

Without the context of the blog post this questions references to, this question is probably a bit hard to follow, so here is the blog post, the original question and the answer: http://www.hivemq.com/building-a-high-availability-mqtt-cluster/